# Dynamic edittext passed to string for another activity

Tags: android, regex, database, listview, android-edittext

I'm trying to setup my program to take edittext from a list view, send to a string. Then to use these strings replace text pulled from database. So depending on what the user selected first there will be between 4-10 edittext for them to fill out. Once they fill out these edittext they will click the confirm button where it takes them to the next activity. On the next activity it take these strings from the edittext where it will do some replacing of text pulled from my database. I have it working for one edittext but I want to set this up dynamically so I have a few lines take care of this function no matter how many edittext fields I had on the previous activity.

code to display edittext page in form of listview

```
public class editpage extends ListActivity {
    public static String editstring1;
    int editCount;
    private dbadapter mydbhelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.edit_list);
        mydbhelper = new dbadapter(this);
        mydbhelper.open();
        fillData();
    }



    private void fillData() {


        Cursor e = mydbhelper.getUserWord();
            startManagingCursor(e);

     // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (TITLE,DATE,NUMBER)
        String[] from = new String[] {dbadapter.KEY_USERWORD,};

        // an array of the views that we want to bind those fields to (in this case text1,text2,text3)
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textType,};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
       SimpleCursorAdapter editadapter = 
       new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.edit_row, e, from, to);
       ListView list = getListView();
       View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, list, false);
       list.addFooterView(footer);
       setListAdapter(editadapter);
       editCount = e.getCount();
        }

        public void onClick(View footer){
            final MediaPlayer editClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button50);
            editClickSound.start();
            EditText editstory = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText));
            editstring1 = editstory.getText().toString();
            startActivity(new Intent("wanted.pro.madlibs.OUTPUT"));
                    };


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);

    }}
```

Next code is my output code that will display results

```
public class output extends ListActivity {
    private dbadapter mydbhelper;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstantState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstantState);
        setContentView(R.layout.outview);
        mydbhelper = new dbadapter(this);
        mydbhelper.open();
        fillData();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, 10);
    }

private final Runnable mTask = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
        String story = textView.getText().toString();
CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
            "edit1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">"+ editpage.editstring1 +"</font>"));
    textView.setText(modifitedText);
    }
};
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    private void fillData() {

        Cursor st = mydbhelper.getStory();
            startManagingCursor(st);

     // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (TITLE,DATE,NUMBER)
        String[] from = new String[] {dbadapter.KEY_TITLESTORY};

        // an array of the views that we want to bind those fields to (in this case text1,text2,text3)
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.outputText};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.out_row, st, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        }


}
```

The code in my database looks something like this

```
This is sample code from edit1. It will display the raw text before they user edit2 it. etc etc
```

Simply put I'm having trouble figuring out/finding help on how to make below code work for me dynamically

```
EditText editstory = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText));
            editstring1 = editstory.getText().toString();

CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
            "edit1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">"+ editpage.editstring1 +"</font>"));
    textView.setText(modifitedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you create the EditTexts in your adapter? And if you do I think you should add an onChange method to your EditTexts and handle the data from there